# Applications of equation $x^y=y^x$

Tags: applications

So there are several ways of finding general positive solutions for the equation $x^y=y^x$. But does this equation appear anywhere in physics or other science ? Or maybe there is some practical purpose for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an overview and some applications, consult this paper by Knoebel (http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Knoebel1981_158.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is essentially given by the Lambert W function, for which you can find a list of applications on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications

Does this help?

Comment: Websites can go down, and that Wikipedia page might be restructured considerably at some point. Can we add a few bullet points?

Comment: It is more about Lambert W function than the equation itself, but still thanks.